# How to get last accessed time?

Tags: java, servlets, httpsession

I want to show the last accessed time on the user's profile page when the user logs in again after logout. I am using HttpSession.
I have three servlets

1. Login
2. Logout
3. Profile

where should I use `long lastTime = session.getLastAccessedTime();`

here is the code:

**Login**

```
    String name = request.getParameter("name");
    String password = request.getParameter("password");

    if (password.equals("admin123")) {
        out.print("Welcome, " + name);
        HttpSession session = request.getSession();
        session.setAttribute("name", name);
    } else {
        out.print("Sorry, username or password error!");
        request.getRequestDispatcher("login.html").include(request, response);
    }
```

**Logout**

```
    HttpSession session = request.getSession();
    session.invalidate();

    out.print("You are successfully logged out!");
```

**Profile**

```
    HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);
    if (session != null) {
        String name = (String) session.getAttribute("name");
        long lastTime = session.getLastAccessedTime();
        out.print(lastTime + "last login time");
        out.print("Hello, " + name + " Welcome to Profile");
```

Comment: `session.getLastAccessedTime()` does not have anything to do with authentication. It is a time of the last request with the `JSESSIONID={sessionId}`. http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSession.html#getLastAccessedTime%28%29

Comment: then how can I get last login time of the user.plz tell me.

Comment: You need to implement such feature yourself. Add `lastAuthenticatedOn` property on your `User` object and update it at the end of the authentication.

Answer (score 0):

do one store store in db when user logouts and use it next time.This is good method. I don't think other methods will work if server restarts .Store in db when user session ends or as per your requirement.If you want to user HttpSession listener have a look http://www.mkyong.com/servlet/a-simple-httpsessionlistener-example-active-sessions-counter/